# Resize Image without distorting or cropping it

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

Users upload an image of any size and we need to resize it so it becomes a square without distorting or cropping the image. Basically, it should do something similar to the "Aspect Fit" content mode in an image view. So if we have a 200x100px png image, I want to make it 200x200px and have the extra 100px in the height be transparent space. It should not crop the image to 200x200.

I tried to use this image processor but it does not do what I want. https://github.com/gavinbunney/Toucan. It only crops the image.

How would I do this in swift and is there a framework that is better than the one I mentioned above to make doing this easier. Basically, I am looking for the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Do you really want to modify the image itself? Or just change the way it is displayed?

Comment: We need to modify the image itself. Not just change the way it is displayed. We are uploading it to our server and it needs to be uploaded in the modified format.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tomasbasham/10533743 - scroll down to the comment header: `Oyvindkg commented on Feb 4`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer, along with example usage...

The scaling code is not mine, it's from: https://gist.github.com/tomasbasham/10533743#gistcomment-1988471

Here is code you can run in a playground to test:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800))

container.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container


// MARK: - Image Scaling.
extension UIImage {

    /// Represents a scaling mode
    enum ScalingMode {
        case aspectFill
        case aspectFit

        /// Calculates the aspect ratio between two sizes
        ///
        /// - parameters:
        ///     - size:      the first size used to calculate the ratio
        ///     - otherSize: the second size used to calculate the ratio
        ///
        /// - return: the aspect ratio between the two sizes
        func aspectRatio(between size: CGSize, and otherSize: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
            let aspectWidth  = size.width/otherSize.width
            let aspectHeight = size.height/otherSize.height

            switch self {
            case .aspectFill:
                return max(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            case .aspectFit:
                return min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            }
        }
    }

    /// Scales an image to fit within a bounds with a size governed by the passed size. Also keeps the aspect ratio.
    ///
    /// - parameter:
    ///     - newSize:     the size of the bounds the image must fit within.
    ///     - scalingMode: the desired scaling mode
    ///
    /// - returns: a new scaled image.
    func scaled(to newSize: CGSize, scalingMode: UIImage.ScalingMode = .aspectFill) -> UIImage {

        let aspectRatio = scalingMode.aspectRatio(between: newSize, and: size)

        /* Build the rectangle representing the area to be drawn */
        var scaledImageRect = CGRect.zero

        scaledImageRect.size.width  = size.width * aspectRatio
        scaledImageRect.size.height = size.height * aspectRatio
        scaledImageRect.origin.x    = (newSize.width - size.width * aspectRatio) / 2.0
        scaledImageRect.origin.y    = (newSize.height - size.height * aspectRatio) / 2.0

        /* Draw and retrieve the scaled image */
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

        draw(in: scaledImageRect)
        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return scaledImage!
    }
}

if let srcimg = UIImage(named: "flags") {

    let w = srcimg.size.width
    let h = srcimg.size.height

    // determine whether width or height is greater
    let longer = max(w, h)

    // create a Square size
    let sz = CGSize(width: longer, height: longer)

    // call scaling function to scale the image to the Square dimensions,
    // using "aspect fit"
    let newImage = srcimg.scaled(to: sz, scalingMode: .aspectFit)

    // create a UIImageView with the resulting image
    let v = UIImageView(image: newImage)
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // add it to the container view
    container.addSubview(v)

}
```